# I want to align my results in columns based on the decimal place

Tags: c++

I want to display my result aligned on  the column by the decimal place.

I have tried to just put `setw(7)` and `setw(6)` in parts of the display but it seems to not change the output at all.

```
int main()
{
    double x;
    char more = 'y';

    while(more=='y' || more=='Y')
    {
        cout << "\n\t\t\tInput x:";
        cin >> x;

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t      LibraryResult\tMyResult" << endl;
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "\n\t\tsin(" << x << ")\t"
         << setprecision(6) << sin(x) << "\t" << mySin(x) << endl;

        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "\n\t\tcos(" << x << ")\t"
         << setprecision(6) << cos(x) << "\t" << myCos(x) << endl;

        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << "\n\t\texp(" << x << ")\t"
         << setprecision(6) << exp(x) << "\t" << myExp(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

I want the resultants of the program to be aligned by decimal, so when you put in a number like 2 the decimals are all in the same column.

Comment: please post a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If you set a precision of 6, a width of 6 or 7 is simply not enough to contain the number. You have to either reduce the precision or increase the width.

Try [playing around](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wJui80e7ePxqVLxY) with the stream manipulators in the following snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const double period = 2 * 3.141592653589793;
    const int steps = 20;
    std::cout << std::string(44, '=') << '\n';   
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << "x" << std::setw(12) << "sin(x)" 
              << std::setw(12) << "cos(x)" << std::setw(14) << "tan(x)" << '\n';
    std::cout << std::string(44, '-') << '\n';
    for(int i = 0; i <= steps; ++i)
    {
        double x = i * period / steps;

        std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << x
                  << std::setprecision(6) << std::setw(12) << std::sin(x)
                  << std::setprecision(6) << std::setw(12) << std::cos(x)
                  << std::setprecision(6)  
                  << std::setw(16)         // <- Try to decrease it 
                  << std::scientific       // <- Try to keep it as std::fixed
                  << std::tan(x) << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::string(44, '-') << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot that really helped, I thought I was just putting them in the wrong place, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must use several manipulators (one is not enough)

You might want to try with the following combination, that right-aligns your numbers, with a fixed number of decimals.

```
std::cout.width(15);
std::cout << std::fixed  << std::setprecision(6) <<  std::right << exp(x) << std::endl;
```

You can find information about manipulators [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/)